# Is there a way to catch all keyboard input in a browser?

Tags: php, javascript, html, web-applications

Is there a way to catch all keyboard input in a browser? Im guessing it would have to be JavaScript.

My problem is that I have a USB Bar Code Scanner which the computer treats as a second keyboard. I dont want the user to have to click on the input box for bar codes to be entered in it. But I also want them to be able to hit key short cuts that perform an action that does not display that input in the text box. Also can the f1 - f12 keys be used in this manner or are they reserved for the browser itself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`keydown` will fire for most keys (certainly more than `keypress`) in most browsers (some, such as Safari 3.0, won't fire any events for modifier keys such as Shift) and all keys in recent browsers. The behaviour of function keys is not a good thing to rely on though.

The following page is an excellent reference for key events in JavaScript: http://unixpapa.com/js/key.html

Answer (score 2):

You can handle the `keypress` event for the `document` object, which will receive almost all keyboard input.

The exact behavior of function keys will depend on the browser.

Answer (score 2):

I did this before. I used a timer. I give the input box focus and start the timer after the first keypress is detected, then if no other keys are pressed within 100 milliseconds I submit the form. The barcode scanner "types" pretty quickly.

You can also intercept the character codes to detect the F-keys.